# cx_freeze: can't find a usable init.tcl in the following directories

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, cx-freeze

As far as I'm aware, `cx_freeze` is the only app able to make Python scripts to `.exe` files. However, I would like to make a GUI `exe` in Python 3. And after freezing a simple Tkinter GUI and running the exe, I get the following error:

```
> _tkinter.TclError: Can't find a usable init.tcl in the following directories:
>     {C:\Users\User\Desktop\tkinter\build\exe.win32-3.1\tcl}
> C:/Users/User/Desktop/tkinter/build/exe.win32-3.1/tcl8.5
> C:/Users/User/Desktop/tkinter/build/lib/tcl8.5
> C:/Users/User/Desktop/tkinter/build/lib/tcl8.5
> C:/Users/User/Desktop/tkinter/lib/tcl8.5
> C:/Users/User/Desktop/tkinter/build/library
> C:/Users/User/Desktop/tk inter/library
> C:/Users/User/Desktop/tkinter/tcl8.5.2/library
> C:/Users/User/Desktop/tcl8.5.2/library

> This probably means that Tcl wasn't installed properly.
```

I am using the *simple setup* cx_freeze option.

My cx_freeze exe bundle is save to the following directory:

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop\tkinter\build\exe.win32-3.1
```

Files are:

```
_ctypes.pyd
_tkinter.pyd
basicLABEL.exe
library.zip
python31.dll
tcl85.dll
tk85.dll
unicodedata.pyd
```

Comment: I've used cx_Freeze to make a python 2.6 & 2.7 .exe's, it's surely possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have just solved the problem myself by copying the `tcl8.5` and `tk8.5` directories, located in the Python 3 installation directory, into the `.exe` folder the app works.

Comment: Just wanted to state that 11/23/2013 cx_freeze using the regular bat file - will do this for you.  You don't need to copy the files (python33).  Cheers!