# Pyinstaller: Can't find a usable init.tcl in the following directories This probably means that tcl wasnt installed properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tcl, pyinstaller

I am working on my tkinter project. And when i try to compile it using pyinstaller i get the error shown in picture. This wasnt happening before reseting my pc:

[image: error image]

The code that im trying to compile:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog, Text, DISABLED, NORMAL, ttk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import pyglet,tkinter
pyglet.font.add_file('font.ttf')
arkaplan = "#000000"
koyugri = "#1c1c1c"

root = tk.Tk()
root.title(f"AcemTube Başlatılıyor...")
root.resizable(False, False)
yer = str(root.winfo_screenwidth()/2 - 350/2).split(".")[0]
yer1 = str(root.winfo_screenheight()/2 - 90/2).split(".")[0]
root.geometry(f"350x90+{yer}+{yer1}")
root.overrideredirect(1)
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=90, width=350, background="#23272a")
canvas.pack()
#baslikutu = tk.Frame(root, bg="#2082b2")
#baslikutu.place(relwidth=1, relheight=0.1)

baslikutu1 = tk.Frame(root, bg=arkaplan)
baslikutu1.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)
baslik = tk.Label(baslikutu1, text=f"AcemTube", bg=arkaplan, fg="white")
baslik.config(font=("Montserrat ExtraBold", "28", "bold italic"))
baslik.place(relwidth=0.65, relheight=0.75, relx=0.299)
frm= tk.Frame()
logo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("acemtubes.png"))
rlbl = tk.Label(baslikutu1, image=logo, bg=arkaplan ,fg="#23272a")
rlbl.place(relwidth=0.31, relheight=0.78)
s = ttk.Style()
s.theme_use("clam")
s.configure("red.Horizontal.TProgressbar", foreground='#23272a', background='#2082b2', troughcolor=koyugri, bordercolor="#2082b2", darkcolor="#2082b2", lightcolor="#2082b2")
prgs = ttk.Progressbar(baslikutu1, style="red.Horizontal.TProgressbar", orient=tk.HORIZONTAL,    length=350, mode="determinate")
prgs.place(rely=0.791)
prgs.start(24)

root.mainloop()`
```

Thanks for reading. Im a noobie so please explain me how to solve this issue. Thanks :)

EDIT: I forgot to say that init.tcl exists in this folder. [Image Of The Tcl Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n36Am.png)

Comment: Sounds similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5523294/cx-freeze-cant-find-a-usable-init-tcl-in-the-following-directories

Comment: i saw that article. Unfortunately didnt help.

Comment: Can you be more specific what you tried and how it failed?

Comment: I tried downgrading to python 3.8.4 tried pyinstaller 3.6 tried to copy tcl files from python etc etc...

Comment: Hi, I have a similar trouble, did you find a working solution?